# Highcharts - tooltip\croshair where there's no point

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have two adjescent Highcharts charts, as per this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mimafogeus/TTms6/1/

I'm trying to light up the relevant crosshair in both graphs when one of them is triggered (so there will be a single long vertical line going through both graphs when you hover over a line).

I understand that you trigger a tooltip (and thus, its crosshair) by calling `setState('hover');` on a point.

The bottom chart, though, is a bar chart, and tooltips are only available for lines where's there's a value of a bar, so I don't always have a parallel point I can select when hovering over a place on the top chart.

Is there a way to trigger a tooltip\crosshair where there is no point?

Answer (score 1):

Two different chart can not share crosshair property, I suggest you to draw both the chart in one chart and share crosshair.

```
tooltip: {
     crosshairs: true,
     shared: true
   }
```

[Working example of Bar chart and Line chart](http://jsfiddle.net/b3AF9/7/)

Comment: The problem is, the charts should be one below the other, and with different axis & grid behavior.

Your suggestion uses one chart with two series. The axis and grid belong to that single chart.

Is it possible to do what I offered using your way with some tweaks?

Comment: yes you can use different axes http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/yaxis/opposite/ it is multiple yAxis, you can change it for multiple xAxis.